# Fourier transform of $e^{-x^2 - y^2 - a x y}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm trying to derive the 2-D Fourier transform of
\begin{gather*}
f(x, y) = e^{-x^2 - y^2 - a x y}
\end{gather*}

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am getting stuck in trying to complete the square inside the integral:

\begin{align*}
\hat f(u, v)
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
f(x, y)
e^{-i (u x + v y)}
dx dy
\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x^2 + y^2 + a x y)}
e^{-i (u x + v y)}
dx dy
\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x^2 + i u x)} e^{-(y^2 + i v y)} e^{-a x y}
dx dy
\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x^2 + i u x + (\frac{i u}{2})^2)} e^{(\frac{i u}{2})^2} e^{-(y^2 + i v y + (\frac{i v}{2})^2)} e^{(\frac{i v}{2})^2} e^{-a x y}
dx dy
\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x + \frac{i u}{2})^2} e^{-(y + \frac{i v}{2})^2} e^{- \frac{u^2}{4} - \frac{v^2}{4}} e^{-a x y}
dx dy
\\
&= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
e^{- \frac{u^2}{4} - \frac{v^2}{4}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
e^{-(y + \frac{i v}{2})^2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x + \frac{i u}{2})^2} 
e^{-a x y}
dx dy
\end{align*}

Namely at the end, how do I integrate over $x$?

\begin{gather*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x + \frac{i u}{2})^2} 
e^{-a x y}
dx
\end{gather*}

Should I change how I aggregate $x$ terms earlier?

\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{2 \pi} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x^2 + i u x)} e^{-(y^2 + i v y)} e^{-a x y}
dx dy
\\
= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
e^{\frac{i v}{2})^2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(y^2 + i v y + \frac{i v}{2})^2)}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x^2 + i u x + a x y)}
dx dy
\end{gather*}

and completing the square of $e^{-(x^2 + i u x + a x y)}$...

\begin{gather*}
= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
e^{(\frac{i v}{2})^2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(y^2 + i v y + (\frac{i v}{2})^2)}
e^{(\frac{i u + a y}{2})^2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x^2 + (i u + a y) x + (\frac{i u + a y}{2})^2)}
dx dy
\\
= \frac{1}{2 \pi} 
e^{(\frac{i v}{2})^2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(y^2 + i v y + (\frac{i v}{2})^2)}
e^{(\frac{i u + a y}{2})^2}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 
e^{-(x+ (\frac{i u + a y}{2})^2)}
dx dy
\end{gather*}

but then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x+c)^2} dx$ is equal to zero...

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why is it true that

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+c)^2} dx = 0?$$

This seems like it is just a $u$-substitution away from the ordinary Gaussian,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} = \sqrt \pi$$

Comment: I would write (with $\alpha = a/2$)
$$
e^{-(x^2+y^2+2\alpha xy)} = e^{-(1-\alpha^2)\,y^2}\,e^{-(x+\alpha\,y)^2}
$$
and now you can first do the Fourier transform in $x$ (just a shifted Gaussian) and then you will have a Fourier transform of a Gaussian only in $y$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer good point, I think I was thinking of the integral of $x e^{-x^2}$ instead of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you, @LL3.14 ! I will try that.